# Can I have anonymous function with "static" variables in Python?

Tags: python, lambda

Can I have anonymous function with "static" variables in Python?

For example

```
lambda x: re.compile(r'foobar').match(x)
```

is not so great, because it may recompile every time it is called (if `re` runs out of cache - thank you responders for pointing out the cache mechanism).

I can do this without recompiling:

```
def f(line):
    try:
        f.c
    except:
        f.c = re.compile(r'foobar')
    return f.c.match(line)
```

How to do it with a lambda, without recompiling?

And well, I don't want to use a helper function, to use inside the lambda.  The whole point of using lambdas is "anonymity".  So yes the lambda is anonymous, and self-contained.

Comment: `re` library has a caching mechanism, so your regex should not be compiled each time function is called.

Comment: In practice I wouldn't worry about that.  The `re` module internally caches 100 regexes, so if you aren't using more than 100 patterns you won't see any significant performance gain from doing this

Comment: why would the second example not recompile?

Comment: For the same reason the first example will not recompile ...  ;)

Comment: I'm mean if we assume that re is not caching (I think the OP just used `re.compile` as an example)

Comment: In general you can just compile the regex once at module level and when use it as often as you like to.

Comment: @hitzg thank you for pointing out, I fixed my example so it does not recompile

Comment: @wim unfortunately I will have more than 100 patterns.  Is there a way to configure the `re` module to cache "everything"

Comment: after you `import re`, you could set the MAXCACHE to whatever you like

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usual trick is to provide a default value for an argument you don't intend to supply.

```
lambda x, regexobject=re.compile(r'foobar'): regexobject.match(x)
```

The default value is evaluated when the `lambda` is defined, not each time it is called.

---

Rather than using the `lambda`, though, I would just define your regular expressions explicitly

```
regex1 = re.compile(r'foobar')
regex2 = re.compile(r'bazquux')
# etc
```

then pass the bound method around where needed. That is, instead of

```
somefunction(lambda x, regexobject=re.compile(r'foobar'): regexobject.match(x))
```

use

```
somefunction(regex1.match)
```

The use case for an anonymous function is one that will only be called once, so there is no sense in binding a name to it. The fact that you are concerned about `re.compile` being called multiple times indicates that the functions will be called several times.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion just to use the bound method.  I see no advantage for trying to apply lambdas here